# Why HashMap produced output 0 for this program?

Tags: java

I do not understand how this java program is showing the output as zero. I believe it should be 1. Per my knowledge it doesn't allows the same key to be used more than once. Can someone please explain this thoroughly ?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Names {
    private Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();

    public void names(){
        m.put("Mickey", "Mouse");
        m.put("Mickey", "Mouse");
    }
    public int size(){
        return m.size();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Names names = new Names();
        System.out.println(names.size());
    }
}
```

Output: 0

Comment: How about calling `names()` to fill the map, _before_ you check the size?

Comment: Your program never adds anything to the map. It creates an empty map, and then prints its size. Of course, it's 0.

Comment: Pedagogically speaking, you are getting this error because you named a non-constructor method the same as your class, If you change your method name from `names` to `putNames` your mistakes will be evident.

Comment: @user1803551 *"you named a non-constructor method the same as your class"* Not really, the case still counts. ;P

Comment: @Tom Which is why I said *Pedagogically speaking* and not *Technically speaking*. I'm advising the OP to name his methods meaningfully.

Comment: Also, a few seconds in the debugger would have shown you the problem. If you need help on using the debugger please tell us what your IDE is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the method you've written to add objects to the HashMap is never being ran, you probably meant to do one of the below things:

```
public void names(){
    m.put("Mickey", "Mouse");
    m.put("Mickey", "Mouse");
}
```

needs to be

```
public Names(){
    m.put("Mickey", "Mouse");
    m.put("Mickey", "Mouse");
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Names names = new Names();
    System.out.println(names.size());
}
```

needs to be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Names names = new Names();
    names.names();
    System.out.println(names.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
public void names(){
    m.put("Mickey", "Mouse");
    m.put("Mickey", "Mouse");
}
```

is not a constructor of your java class.
You should define it like

```
public Names(){
    m.put("Mickey", "Mouse");
    m.put("Mickey", "Mouse");
}
```

Read this link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html